# clang -flto does not work on Android

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, clang

I have an NDK shared library project for Android using Clang with Cmake.

When I add `-flto` to C/C++ flags, I'm getting the following error:

> ```
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
>   clang++: error: unable to execute command: Aborted (core dumped)
>   clang++: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> ```

I'm adding `-flto` into `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`.

I have also increased RAM memory to 10 GB of my Linux VM. Tested on Windows7 and got the same result. Android Studio and NDK+SDK are the latest versions.

For testing, just add the following lines into your cmake project;

```
string(CONCAT CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} " -flto ")
string(CONCAT CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} " -flto ")
string(CONCAT CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} " -flto -fuse-ld:gold ") # optional
```

Also I have tried to add `-flto -fuse-ld:gold` into `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE`. Android studio Cmake output stucks on this message; I waited 30 minutes but it stays as it is.

```
End of search list.
[36/36] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
```

I can compile the code by adding `-flto` into `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE`, but not in C/C++ flags.

I hope I could give enough information for the issue.

Comment: Any help? You can add `-flto`to C or C++ flags to test it easily on your Android NDK project.